# How to keep my table looking nice when zooming?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am making a website to post solutions to an Algebra book I am reading during this summer and I am having trouble making my tables look nice when zooming.

https://codepen.io/jedidreyfus/pen/jmYwMd

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Abstract Algebra  D&amp;F Exercises </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="exo">
    </div>
    <div id="list">
      <h1>List of exercises from Abstract Algebra by Dummit and Foote (3rd. ed.)</h1>
<h2>Preliminaries</h2>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Section 1</th>
<td><a onclick="loadex(0,1,1)" href="#"> 0.1.1 </a></td>
<td><a onclick="loadex(0,1,2)" href="#"> 0.1.2 </a></td>
<td><a onclick="loadex(0,1,3)" href="#"> 0.1.3 </a></td>
<td><a onclick="loadex(0,1,4)" href="#"> 0.1.4 </a></td>
<td><a onclick="loadex(0,1,5)" href="#"> 0.1.5 </a></td>
<td><a onclick="loadex(0,1,6)" href="#"> 0.1.6 </a></td>
<td><a onclick="loadex(0,1,7)" href="#"> 0.1.7 </a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Section 2</th>
<td><a onclick="loadex(0,2,1)" href="#"> 0.2.1 </a></td>
<td><a onclick="loadex(0,2,2)" href="#"> 0.2.2 </a></td>
<td><a onclick="loadex(0,2,3)" href="#"> 0.2.3 </a></td>
<td><a onclick="loadex(0,2,4)" href="#"> 0.2.4 </a></td>
<td><a onclick="loadex(0,2,5)" href="#"> 0.2.5 </a></td>
<td><a onclick="loadex(0,2,6)" href="#"> 0.2.6 </a></td>
<td><a onclick="loadex(0,2,7)" href="#"> 0.2.7 </a></td>
<td><a onclick="loadex(0,2,8)" href="#"> 0.2.8 </a></td>
<td><a onclick="loadex(0,2,9)" href="#"> 0.2.9 </a></td>
<td><a onclick="loadex(0,2,10)" href="#"> 0.2.10 </a></td>
<td><a onclick="loadex(0,2,11)" href="#"> 0.2.11 </a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Section 3</th>
<td><a onclick="loadex(0,3,1)" href="#"> 0.3.1 </a></td>
<td><a onclick="loadex(0,3,2)" href="#"> 0.3.2 </a></td>
<td><a onclick="loadex(0,3,3)" href="#"> 0.3.3 </a></td>
<td><a onclick="loadex(0,3,4)" href="#"> 0.3.4 </a></td>
<td><a onclick="loadex(0,3,5)" href="#"> 0.3.5 </a></td>
<td><a onclick="loadex(0,3,6)" href="#"> 0.3.6 </a></td>
<td><a onclick="loadex(0,3,7)" href="#"> 0.3.7 </a></td>
</tr>
</table>

    </div>
    <div id="about"><a onclick="loadabout()" href="#">About</a></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

When you zoom in, the table will start to distort. For example, the titles on the left will start breaking words and the size of the columns won't scale well with the zooming. Is there anyway to make all the sizes and spacings in the table scale well ?

Comment: What browser are you using? In Chrome I zoomed to 250% and couldn't get your table to break unexpectedly.

Comment: @hughes Sorry, I had changed the codepen by adding a width to the table as suggested by an answer below. It was fine but I don't want to hardcode width because I need to change the table often. I switched it back, now you can see how the section number goes on another line when zooming.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just give your whole table and your first column a fixed width.

```
<table style="width: 800px">
<tr>
<th width="100">Section 1</th>
....
```

Comment: Thanks ! Is there a way to make this more flexible ? My tables change size all the times when I add exercises and I don't want to need to change the css each time.